# Can't install activeadmin for Rails 4.1.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

**My Environment:**

- Xubuntu 14.04
- ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161)[x86_64-linux]
- Rails 4.1.0

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem 'polyamorous', github: 'activerecord-hackery/polyamorous'
gem "formtastic", github: "justinfrench/formtastic"
gem "ransack", github: "activerecord-hackery/ransack"
gem "devise", github: "plataformatec/devise"
```

When I run:

```
$bundle install
Fetching git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
```

And it lasts endless...

I noticed it's taking time also when I try to install one of the following gems:

```
gem "ransack", github: "activerecord-hackery/ransack"
gem "formtastic", github: "justinfrench/formtastic"
```

**UPDATE**

This issue was happening for 6 days and just worked today.
Have no idea what was happening.
I wish I knew about `--verbose` option as **@SreekanthGS** was pointing out below, we'd have some idea about the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see what's happening within the bundle install process by using the verbose switch.

```
bundle install --verbose
```

Comment: Very strange. Right after you replied bundle install ran fine. Though, I was having same issue on Mac OS X, so I will update the post as soon as I get results for "bundle install --verbose". Thanks.

Comment: If it happens at random, it might well be a network issue of some sort.

Comment: Could very well be. Verbose could help you catch such network glitches.